# Posts deleted by owner shouldn't show up in Low Quality Posts review audits

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15498141) in Low Quality Posts and got review banned for that:

[image]

However, I still think that my review was appropriate. The reason why it showed up as an audit is because the person who posted it deleted it, and since it was deleted, the system thought that all posts like that should be deleted.

This answer does look like an attempt to answer the question. It may have some issues, but it's clearly not something that should be deleted by the community. The author deleted it for some reason, and he is perfectly allowed to do that, but that doesn't mean that everything that looks like that should be deleted. The Looks OK button is for posts that should not be deleted by the community which is clearly the case here. If I had to review that again, I would not have reviewed it differently.

I therefore think that posts that were deleted by the owner should not show up as low quality posts. The fact that the owner decided to delete it does not necessarily mean that the community should delete it.

<sub>PS: For moderators reading this: If you agree that this audit was incorrect, please consider lifting my review ban. Also whether you agree about this specific case or not, please take a look at [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/349538) and [this answer to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/349538) and consider implementing it.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't because the OP deleted it. The post had a spam flag on it (and had a negative score) which indicates to the system that "Looks OK" is not the correct action.

In this case given the context reviewers are supposed to take into account, your review history and the fact I can see that "Looks OK" is not an unreasonable choice I've lifted your review ban.