# Failed Low Quality Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I had [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15638223) in the low-quality post review section as an audit. And I got

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
>   spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will
>   find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. Please delete or
>   recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.

Did I miss something while reviewing? It may not be the *right* answer, but it didn't seem to qualify as a low-quality post.
Also if a post is deleted by the owner does it qualify as a **low-quality post**?

Comment: Maybe it picked up a spam flag due to the undisclosed linking to their own github repo. Needs a mod to verify and if that is the case I think they should clear that flag as this is indeed a bad audit.

Comment: I just saw this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345316/posts-deleted-by-owner-shouldnt-show-up-in-low-quality-posts-review-audits) with the same audit.. It is a false flag right?

Comment: I pinged Jon in chat, he'll take a look

Comment: This has occurred before - it's sadly a not great audit as it had flags that shouldn't have been there (see the linked dupe)... you haven't been banned from review, so thanks for bringing it up, and sorry about that.

Comment: No problem..wanted to make sure I wasnt missing something.. Thanks for clearing it up..On a related note is it possible to remove such bad audits from the system? @JonClements

Comment: @suraj it's removed now - note that audits are automatically picked by the system and there's not much that moderators can do to remove it except by doing what we can do make the post a non-candidate for it.

Comment: @suraj thanks for your understanding and don't be dishearten by a one off "ouch"